# Choppy animation while pushing UITableViewController with static cells

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I am having a UITableViewController with static cells. When I am performing a push segue, the animation is somewhat choppy. I have figured out which line of code is giving the problem. In viewWillAppear(_:) method of the UITableViewController, I am setting self.tableview.isHidden = true. If I remove this line of code then it works fine. However, I need this line as I am making a network call and I want to show the tableview only after the response is received. Any solutions to this issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the TableView's Hidden property from the Storyboard. You can find the checkbox for this under "View > Drawing" in Attributes inspector. You can find the screenshot for this [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQ7FR.png).

That being said, you should find a better approach to indicate that API calls are being made. I would use a protocol that your viewcontrollers could conform to.

```
protocol ActivityIndicating {
    func showLoading()
    func hideLoading()
}
```

And in your ViewController class, you would have something like this

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, ActivityIndicating {
    //protocol methods
    func showLoading() {
        //implement logic to hide tableview, show indicator, etc.
    }

    func hideLoading() {
        //implement logic to show tableview, hide indicator, etc.
    }

    func someFunctionThatMakesAPIcalls() {
        showLoading()
        //makeAPICall and call hideLoading() once the api succeeds or fails
    }
}
```